# A Regex that search for lines that contains a string, and not contains another string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to analyze an error log. So I decided to search for all the error header in the error log using Notepad++ so I can get all the first line of the errors on search result (which contains short description about the error) to determine if I need to look deeper into it. But the error log apparently is full of 'useless' error log from one kind of event, like 90% of it, so it kinds of hide the real error, like searching a needle in haystack.

So from this example made up error log:

```
ERROR on Server1: Network connection reset.
    DETAIL: The client is gone.
ERROR on Server2: Network connection reset.
    DETAIL: The client is gone.
ERROR on Server1: Network connection reset.
    DETAIL: The client is gone.
ERROR on Server1: Null Pointer Error.
    DETAIL: Object 'Cart' does not exists.
    STACKTRACE: 
        at UpdateCart function
        at AddProducttoCart function
ERROR on Server2: Network connection reset.
    DETAIL: The client is gone.
ERROR on Server2: IO Error
    DETAIL: The resource on URL (www.example.com/data.xls) does not exists.
ERROR on Server2: Network connection reset.
    DETAIL: The client is gone.
```

I want to create a regex on Notepad++ search that search for line that contains string "ERROR on" but does not contain "Network connection reset", so the search result will only contain:

```
ERROR on Server1: Null Pointer Error.
ERROR on Server2: IO Error
```

How can I do that? I've read somewhere that inverse matching on regex is somewhat hard and unusual, but it's possible. Thanks.

Btw, I've tried some other way to do this, like finding for "ERROR on" + `(.*)` + "Network connection reset", then replace it with empty string, so that next time I search for "ERROR on", they will not appear. But the error log becomes scrambled with weird symbols after the search and replace, and Notepad++ kinda crashing after that. I don't know. I never have any luck search and replace on Notepad++ using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*?\bNetwork connection reset\b).*\bERROR on\b.*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^ERROR on (?:(?!Network connection reset).)*$
```

You can use a `lookahead` in your regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pV0fH2/1